# How to compute current integral over time in a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a `dataframe` with columns `speed` and `timestamp` which is a simple range between 0 and 100. I would like to compute the following integral in a new column `distance` for each timestamp.

[image]

What I did :

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

#some code ... 

dataframe.loc[:, "distance"] = [
     np.trapz(
          y=dataframe["speed"].iloc[:t], 
          x=dataframe["timestamp"].iloc[:t],
     )
     for t in range(0, dataframe.shape[0])
]
```

However, I do suspect there is more pythonic and efficient way to compute this integral, which better use the power and syntax of pandas, and so on.

Does someone have an idea ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably you are looking for

```
dataframe["distance"] = dataframe["speed"].cumsum() * freq
```

where `freq` is the frequency of your time series (for example `freq=10` if you have 10 records per second).

Comment: It will compute the integral using the rectangle method. But that's a good point to start.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, the trapezoidal method should be given by `dataframe["distance"] = (dataframe.iloc[:-1, "speed"].cumsum() + dataframe.iloc[1:, "speed"].cumsum()) / 2 * freq`. Do you agree?

Comment: I accept your answer.  But, I would talk about `width` instead of `freq`. Typically the `width` is computed using : `width = (dataframe["timestamp"] - dataframe["timestamp"].min()) / (freq * dataframe["timestamp"] + 1)`. Where `freq` is the frequency of the `timestamp`, i.e.   `freq =  dataframe["timestamp"].size / (dataframe["timestamp"].max() -  dataframe["timestamp"].min())`.